Viewing Google Play reviews from ALL countries?
I want to view the reviews on Google Play for one app, but there are only 2 one-star reviews from my country and neither of them are particularly helpful.
Is there a way to view ALL the reviews (regardless of the region of my account)?
I've tried the "&gl=en" trick found in a similar StackExchange post, but it won't work, returning a HTTP 400 status instead.

Normally the language parameter on Google web pages is hl not gl. Therefore hl=en  should give you reviews of people with default language English (not sure if this will include reviews from other countries).

gl works (the parameter, not sure whether it affects reviews or not), but it is a geolocation parameter and accepts country code, not language code, e.g. gl=us.

Thank you @AndrewT., this worked for me. You need to be signed out of Google Play for it to work.
